# How to reset react-countup

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using `react-countup` I want to reset the counter when it reaches the end using either render props of hooks.

I've tried various configurations but I haven't been able to work it out.

```
<CountUp className='countup' 
  end={100}
  duration={5}
  reset={true}
/>
```

The above code doesn't work.
The docs says the following about how to reset using render props.

```
reset: () => void
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this to get the counter to reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset `react-countup` you have [`onEnd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup#onend--pauseresume-reset-start-update---void) prop.

> `onEnd` is a callback function on transition end.

```
<CountUp className='countup' 
    end={100}
    duration={5}
    onEnd={({ pauseResume, reset, start, update }) => reset()}
/>
```

To make it `start` again,

```
<CountUp className='countup' 
    end={100}
    duration={5}
    onEnd={({ pauseResume, reset, start, update }) => start()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As displayed in the [complete example](https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup#complete-example), you can extract the reset function from the react-countup hook like this:

```
const { countUp, start, pauseResume, reset, update } = useCountUp({...});
```

Now calling the reset function in your code will reset it:

```
<div onClick={reset}>Reset Counter</div>
```